# Which groupbox is a clicked button in. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, controls

I have a windows form with a set of groupboxes each containing a number of buttons. Each button represents a time slot in a day (8:00 - 9:00, 13:30 - 14:30) which has either been booked or not booked (by another user). When pressing on a button I need it to display information about who booked the slot(ie name, postcode) which is already stored in a database. I can get the information from the database and display it as long as have the ID of the slot booked. To get this I need a date and a time. Each groupbox has corresponding date. When a user clicks a button I need it to tell me which groupbox it is in so I can use the associated date to find the information of the customer that booked it. How can I code this in c# to find what groupbox the clicked button is in.

Comment: Did you already try something? Where exactly did you get stuck? BTW: I removed the "visual-studio" tag (which is for question regarding the development environment itself) and added the "winforms" tag.

Comment: The click event has a Sender property.  That is your Button and that one has a Parent property. That is the container control the Button is in. So follow the Parent property to find  a GroupBox you are interested in. Besides that what you are doing sound wrong. You seems to have a mix of Data and UI. UI should only show data not be the container to store data.

Comment: @Ralf Thats seems to help fix part of the issue. My main problem is that I have a lot of buttons so I don't want to have to do this
'private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GroupBox grp = (GroupBox)btn.Parent;

            MessageBox.Show (grp.Text);

        }'
For every button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent object of the sender from the ButtonClickEvent.

```
 private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            GroupBox grp = (GroupBox)btn.Parent;

            MessageBox.Show (grp.Text);

        }
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this for all the buttons without having to put this in every button click method

Comment: Just use the shown method for every button. If you had setup one you can simply select it in the winforms editor. Or connect all buttons and the one button click handler in code. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: @CharlieGraydon If you have the group boxes in the same container (`Form` for example) then you can subscribe to one `Button.Click` event handler as shown in this answer like this: `foreach (var btn in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(c => c.Controls.OfType<Button>())) btn.Click += button1_Click;`. Do this in the Form's ctor or `Load` event. Make sure to import `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: @dr.null So if I click on any button it will call the button1_click method